# How can I configure my Django application to use separate databases for different superusers?

Tags: django, database, postgresql, multiple-databases, superuser

How can I create multiple databases in my Django project, where each superuser has access to their own database but not to other databases (even in the dashboard)?

I have tried to create multiple databases in `setting.py` and `models.py` but it is not working.

Comment: It can be easily achieved via settings.py, can you share how you are trying to achieve it, add code snippet and/or what error you are getting